How to ensure API events are processed sequentially
Question: How can we ensure that multiple API events for the same record are processed sequentially and not in parallel.
Background: We are building a securities trading application. The trading engine runs in a Salesforce Org and is implemented using APEX. The trading client runs in a NodeJS Webapp on Heroku.
Users submit buy and sell orders via the trading client. The trading client NodeJS process then makes an API call to the trading engine in Salesforce. The trading engine then matches those buy and sell orders in real-time.
Problem Scope: If 2 users both submit a trade for the same security at the same time, then the trading engine running in Salesforce (APEX) will process those trades at the same time rather than sequentially.  This behaviour can result in 2 buy orders both matching with a single sell order, which effectively sells the same parcel of shares twice.  The expected behaviour is that the first buy order received matches with the sell order and the second buy order is not matched as the sell order has already matched with the first buy order and therefore is no longer eligible to match with the second buy order.
I have solved this problem in other platforms by either synchronising on a lock object or using a FIFO queue with a single worker thread, but I am not sure how to solve this problem in Salesforce APEX.
Any advice is much appreciated.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm . Why are you doing this on Salesforce? Sure, one of the first ECNs (Island) was written in FoxPro on DOS but that was late 90s, we're in 2024 now.

Create a custom endpoint to capture the information required to create a trade record.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm
example:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm
Before putting in a trade record lock the security record with the "FOR UPDATE" soql statement.
Security__c sec = [select Id, LastTrade__c from Security__c where Id =: secId FOR UPDATE];
If (sec.Trade__c != null){
   // return or throw an error
}
//insert trade record
sec.Trade__c = trad.Id;
update sec; // release record

At some point after inserting the trade later update the actual sec setting a field that contains the "Trade__c".
SOQL for update reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm
